# UI is not updating while some function takes time to execution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, user-interface

I am doing some image processing and with this also showing the loading. Problem is that loading is not updating.

```
for (ALAsset *asset in assets) {
  weakSelf.HUD.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d",count,assets.coun
  weakSelf.HUD.progress=(CGFloat)count/assets.count;
  [objDoc setImageProcess:asset];
  count++;
}
```

Here the HUD is not updating its value. If I put the delay then its showing. Here `setImageProcess` takes time while processing.

Comment: Stop using the "Xcode" tag. It does not apply to your question.

Comment: Ok i will keep in mind any soluction?

Comment: Do the image processing in the background so it doesn't block the main thread.

Comment: But i want to do some task after completation of image process. how can i do that. if i use perfromselector in background then how can i know that process finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI updates take place on the main thread in iOS and Mac OS. If you have time-consuming code that runs on a background thread, you can send messages to the main thread to update the UI and it works perfectly.

If you are running your time-consuming code on the main thread, UI changes get accumulated, and only get rendered to the screen when your app returns and visits the event loop.

So, if you have a loop that does a bunch of time-consuming tasks and doesn't return until the whole loop is finished, it doesn't work because the UI updates don't take place until you return.

You need to refactor your code to return between iterations. Something like this:

Create an instance variable assetCount:

```
@interface myClass: UIViewController;
{
  NSInteger assetIndex;
}
@end.
```

Then

```
-(void) viewDidLoad;
{
  assetIndex = 0;
  [self processAssets];
}

- (void) processAssets;
{
  if (assetIndex >= assets.count)
    return;
  ALAsset *asset = assets[assetIndex];
  weakSelf.HUD.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d/%d",count,assets.coun
  weakSelf.HUD.progress=(CGFloat)count/assets.count;
  [objDoc setImageProcess:asset];
  assetIndex++;
  count++;

  //The following method call queues up a method call 
  //for the next time your app visits the event loop. (plus an optional delay)
  [self performsSelector: processAssets 
    withObject: nil
    afterDelay: 0];
}
```

The method above processes 1 asset, then queues a delayed call to itself. Even though the delay value is 0 it still fixes your problem. That's because the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: method always returns immediately, and queues up the method call for the next pass through the event loop. In the next pass through the event loop, the system does housekeeping like updating the screen, then checks for pending calls like this one. If there is a delay it will start a timer. If not, it will trigger your method call.

You have a variable count in the code you posted that might work as an array index. I added a new instance variable assetIndex to track the current array index. Your code also uses the term weakSelf, suggesting that this code is being executed from a block. It might be that there is a cleaner way to handle this, but you would need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

For all UI changes, you have to call in mainthread. Verify that the current functions is called in main thread:

```
BOOL isMainThread = [[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread]
```

Comment: the normal process is: you put functions that take time in to background thread, when it needs to update UI, call the updates of UI in mainthread (using GCD async, performSelectorOnMainThread, add to [NSOperationQueue mainQueue],..). Else, it will block your main thread from updating the UI.