# ios visuals not updating while process takes place. (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, swift3

I have a process that takes some time to process:

```
for n in 0..<currentAmount {
    if gcd(random(max: Int(randRange.value)), random(max: Int(randRange.value))) == 1{
        gcdCounter += 1
    }
    piProgress.setProgress(Float(Double(n)/Double(currentAmount)), animated: false)
}
```

Firstly, the progress bar is referenced correctly. There seems to be something going on that I'm unaware of as when the button that activated this loop enters, the button stays 'greyed out' until the loop is done and the progress bar doesn't update at all. If I replaced the last line in the loop with

```
print(Float(Double(n)/Double(currentAmount))
```

I can see the progress pass perfectly well in the console, so why isn't the view updating? I read on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147931/ui-is-not-updating-while-some-function-takes-time-to-execution) it's to do with which threads the processes are running on, but that's in objective-c I think, not Swift 3. Please help. I like to see my app doing *something*.

EDIT: After looking through, I found this resource very useful for learning GCD: http://www.appcoda.com/grand-central-dispatch/

Comment: Rules of threading have nothing to do with the language. The other question you linked applies to your case just as much as it does to that one.

Comment: I didn't understand any of the code written there, is it against some rules to post in another language, I thought it would've been useful to anyone else looking for the same thing I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because all UI updates, ie. updates to any UILabel, UIButton etc have to be done on the main thread, ie. `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.myLabel.text = "progress is now \(pc) %"`

It's good to get things done off the main thread, but UI must be updated on the main thread. That includes anything that affects autolayout.